# Why is this giving me an Arithmetic Error in java?

Tags: java, math

So for some reason this is giving me division by 0 error, any ideas?

```
package euler;
public class LargePrimeFactor {
    public static long max = 600851475143L;

    public static int isPrime() {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            if(max % i == 0)count += i;
        }
        return count;
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(max/isPrime());

    }
 }
```

Comment: `i` is an `int`, i.e. it will overflow and eventually be `0`. Side note: `i < max` will always be true by the same line of reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error as the value of `i` will be `overflow` after `Integer.MAX_VALUE` due to `Integer overflow`. Your `max` is a type of `long` holding value `600851475143L` (which is greater than the Integer.MAX_VALUE)  but `i` is int. So at a point of time, `i` will eventually reach to `0` due to `overflow` and `max % i` = `600851475143L/0` will throw the error. To solve the issue I will suggest making `i` type of long.

```
   long count = 0;
   for(long i = 1; i < max; i++) {
        if(max % i == 0)count += i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `i` is of type `int`. [The maximum value of an `int` is `(2^31) - 1 = 2147483647`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). When you add one to the maximum `int` value, it will overflow, becoming the minimum int value (`-2^31 = -2147483648`). This is called a [ring arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) Continuing to add 1 to this variable, it will eventually become `0`, resulting in an `DivisionByZeroException` (remember, [division and modulus are semantically coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation-)).

As an aside: By the same reasoning, you can see that `i < max` will always be true.